# Hash algorithms used in C++ std

Tags: c++, hash

I am looking for the information on what hash algorithm is used in C++ `std::hash<std::string>` specialization. The closest I could get is this information from my `include/c++/7/bits/basic_string.h`:

```
  /// std::hash specialization for string.
  template<>
    struct hash<string>
    : public __hash_base<size_t, string>
    {
      size_t
      operator()(const string& __s) const noexcept
      { return std::_Hash_impl::hash(__s.data(), __s.length()); }
    };
```

Then `include/c++/7/bits/functional_hash.h`:

```
  struct _Hash_impl
  {
    static size_t
    hash(const void* __ptr, size_t __clength,
     size_t __seed = static_cast<size_t>(0xc70f6907UL))
    { return _Hash_bytes(__ptr, __clength, __seed); }

    template<typename _Tp>
      static size_t
      hash(const _Tp& __val)
      { return hash(&__val, sizeof(__val)); }

    template<typename _Tp>
      static size_t
      __hash_combine(const _Tp& __val, size_t __hash)
      { return hash(&__val, sizeof(__val), __hash); }
  };
```

And finally `include/c++/7/bits/hash_bytes.h`:

```
  // Hash function implementation for the nontrivial specialization.
  // All of them are based on a primitive that hashes a pointer to a
  // byte array. The actual hash algorithm is not guaranteed to stay
  // the same from release to release -- it may be updated or tuned to
  // improve hash quality or speed.
  size_t
  _Hash_bytes(const void* __ptr, size_t __len, size_t __seed);
```

There are actually two questions:

1. Does this mean that C++ uses the same hash algorithms for all non-trivial data types?
2. What is the algorithm that C++ uses for `_Hash_bytes`?

Comment: This will depend on the C++ implementation that you’re using. I assume this is libstdc++?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, it's `libstdc++`. If you know more about it I would definitely appreciate a few more words on what it does and why.

Comment: @foki Is your question specifically about the libstdc++ implementation of the standard library? Because as mentioned, in general, it is completely implementation-defined what hash function is used (as long as it satisfies the general properties of a hash function).

Comment: @walnut My question is about the standard library but I am also interested in general discussion. In other words, why `libstdc++` chooses Murmur and FNV? I guess that Murmur is less crypto-safe than FNV, but still evenly distributes over the range, thus probably enough for some non-crypto hashing. Do you know of some other implementations and their rationales for using different hashes?

Comment: @foki Just as general note: `std::hash` is not meant to be used for crypto purposes. It is not cryptographically safe and before C++14 it even was required to produce the same results for the same inputs, even across multiple executions, making it vulnerable to denial-of-service attacks and the like.

Comment: @walnut Good to know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The details of a [hash function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) are left as implementation details.  A hash needs to return the same value during the execution of the program for two values that are equal, and the returned hashes should be evenly distributed over the range of the returned value.  (Not requiring a hash to return the same value in different executions allows the use of salted hashes.)

Since the `Hash_bytes` function is an implementation-specific function (the name, starting with and underscore followed by an uppercase letter, is an implementation reserved identifier), so you'd have to look that up in your implementation's library source to see what it does.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like it uses Murmur and FNV (depending on the type) https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/hash_bytes.cc#L74 Are you aware of some other implementations out there?